# How does Range work?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this partial code.

```
  ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B150").Copy
  Milestone.Sheets("Transit").Activate
  ActiveSheet.Paste
  TransitFile.Close

  'Vlookup L4 Names
  Range("F2").Formula = "=1+5"
```

"Transit" is the second worksheet in my workbook.  In the last line (the formula line), it inputs the formula into the first sheet of my workbook (Sheet1).  I don't understand why is that when the "Transit" sheet is the one that is Active.  Can anybody help me explain why?

And how come I don't need to use ActiveSheet in Range("F2").Formula but I need to if I use select as in ActiveSheet.Range("A2:B4").Select

Comment: What is Milestone? If you replace Milestone with ActiveWorkbook it will set that sheet to active.

Comment: Milestone is the name of a Workbook

Answer (score 1):

To avoid mistakes you can use `sheets("Name").range`. If you simply use `range` the program will assume you want the range in the active sheet.

For example,

```
Sheets("Feuil1").Select
Range("A1:B150").Copy
```

works as well as

```
Sheets("Feuil1").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B150").Copy
```

The best thing to try is to use `Sheets("Feuil1").Range("A1:B150").Copy` so excel knows which range of which sheet to use

Comment: It is generally frowned upon to use .Select  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros  They also frown on .Activate but I have been using that for years without any issues.

Comment: So in my code, "Transit" is the active sheet.  But it's pasting the formula (last line) in my first worksheet ("Sheet1").  Why is that?  Sheet1 is not the active sheet, right?

Comment: If i understand well, it's "Transit". Go in your macro and go execute your program step by step and you'll see which sheet is used and everything (F8)